# Get number of records returned from select in SQR

Tags: oracle, sqr

I have an SQR `Begin-Select` statement which `SELECTS` a bunch of data and returns it for processing the SQR report. There is a possibility that the `Begin-Select` will return nothing, so that means there is nothing to report.

How would I check if the `Begin-Select` returns no rows in it's statement?

I thought about including a `COUNT(*)` in the `Begin-Select`, but I don't want to `GROUP BY` anything. Here's what my `Begin-Select` looks like.

```
Begin-Select On-Error=Global-Got-Fatal-SQL-Error
B.InvrExtAcctNbr        &InvrLoanNbr
A.AcctNbr               &AcctNbr
C.RtxnNbr               &AcctGrpNbr

    !- Process each record
    #Debug Show 'Processing AcctNbr: ' &AcctNbr
    !Do Process-Record
    #Debug Show 'Processed AcctNbr: ' &AcctNbr

 FROM FooBar    A,
       JohnDoe  B,
       SQRNoob  C
 WHERE A.QueNbr = $QueNbr /* 123 */
      AND A.QueSubNbr = $QueSubNbr /* 456 */
      AND A.ApplNbr = $ApplNbr /* 789 */
        AND A.AcctNbr = C.AcctNbr
        AND A.RtxnNbr = B.AcctGrpNbr
 ORDER BY A.AcctNbr
End-Select
```

I want to check if anything got returned from the `Begin-Select`. I've tried this:

```
Begin-Select On-Error=Global-Got-Fatal-SQL-Error
COUNT(A.AcctNbr)        &TotalRows
B.InvrExtAcctNbr        &InvrLoanNbr
A.AcctNbr               &AcctNbr
C.RtxnNbr               &AcctGrpNbr
...
```

But I don't want to use a `GROUP BY` clause at the end of my statement. I also don't want to break it up into two seperate `SELECT` statements. One for the actual selection of data and the other for `COUNT(A.AcctNbr)`.

Is there any other way to get the amount of rows returned from this SELECT statement.

My whole issue is I don't have to process the form if **no** rows are returned. So in reality I only need to check if the `Begin-Select` returns **one or more** rows. If it returns **no** rows, then I would just stop processing the SQR.

Comment: Did my answer not give you what you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, brute force method:

```
Let #Count = 0
Begin-Select
Variables
   add 1 to #Count
From etc
End-Select
If #Count = 0
```

Easiest way I can think of - I tried #SQL-COUNT but that only works for Insert, Delete, and Update statements, not select.